# Why does updating state using React Hooks, MomentJS object and interval/timeout not trigger re-render?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I'm trying to make a countdown timer using React-Native, React Hooks, MomentJS and (setTimeout/setInterval). Whatever approach I try to use, it fails. The problem is that component is never re-rendered.

I tried to follow the official React Hooks documentation, a few articles on Medium, for example [The Iceberg of React Hooks](https://medium.com/@sdolidze/the-iceberg-of-react-hooks-af0b588f43fb) but nothing works.

One possibility is that it needs deep clone of the MomentJS object, but it's an inefficient approach I guess.

This is one of the reproducible examples that I've tried.

```
const Timer = () => {
  const [time, setTime] = useState(moment.duration(30, 'seconds'))
  const intervalRef = useRef()

  useEffect(() => {
    intervalRef.current = setTimeout(() => {
      setTime(prevTime => prevTime.subtract(1, 'second'))
    }, 1000)

    return () => {
      clearInterval(intervalRef.current)
      intervalRef.current = null
    }
  })

  return (
    <View>
      {time.asSeconds()}
    </View>
  )
```

Comment: Mutating the object isn't what you should with `set*()` (ad absurdum - you do not even need to call `setTime()` in that case). To avoid re-rendering when state/properties do not change is one of those basic optimization that makes React easy to use. To create a new `duration` object is a negligible overhead and you can quickly do it using `clone()`. Alternatively you might consider to use `number` instead of `moment.Duration` and to create a new object when rendering. Also note that you do not need `intervalRef`, you can save `const ref = setTimeout(...); return () => clearInterval(ref);`

Comment: It's odd. I always thought that in order to not-rerender a component when the state did changed but the object was identical you had to implement it as a pure component

Comment: the state hasn't actually changed though, the reference to the object is the same

Comment: @WillJenkins in non-functional components calling `setState` always rerenders. Thats why I was confused, though now that I think about it set state probably always clones the state

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're correct, it isn't re-rendering because your moment object is the same (but mutated) on every tick. You can easily get it working by adding `.clone()` in your `setTime` updater:

```
const Timer = () => {
  const [time, setTime] = useState(moment.duration(30, "seconds"));
  const intervalRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    intervalRef.current = setTimeout(() => {
      setTime(prevTime => prevTime.clone().subtract(1, 'second'))
    }, 1000)

    return () => {
      clearInterval(intervalRef.current)
      intervalRef.current = null
    }
  })

  return <div>{time.asSeconds()}</div>;
};
```

Working sandbox here: https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-euler-e8xg5

Answer (score 1):

> One possibility is that it needs deep clone of the MomentJS object, but it's an inefficient approach I guess.

Yes exactly. React doesn't rerender if the current and the previous state equal. You could just store the seconds in the state.

And you don't need that ref.

```
const Timer = () => {
  const [time, setTime] = useState(30 /*s*/)

  useEffect(() => {
    const timeout = setTimeout(() => {
      setTime(prevTime => prevTime - 1);
    }, 1000)

    return () => clearTimeout(timeout);
  }, [time])

  return (
   <View>
     {time}
   </View>
 );
```

Comment: Isn't there a memory leak? If you setTimeout every time "time" gets updated, it will create a new timeout, won't it?

Comment: @honza exactly, it will create a new timeout every second.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I exchanged setTimout with setInterval in my head